# Does bower install need to be run in the same folder as bower.json?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, bower, bower-install

I'm using the express generator https://github.com/expressjs/generator and mixing the angular seed project https://github.com/angular/angular-seed into it to create a lightweight scaffold for a mean stack app.

I would like to be able to run `npm start` to install all dependencies including the front end ones.  The problem is that the angular/front end related files are not in the root directory, but rather in the "public" sub-directory.  **I know I can create an `npm start` script which runs `bower install` but I don't know how to make the start script descend into the public sub-directory and then run `bower install`**.

**My question is does `bower install` try to find a bower.json file in sub-directories or does it stop searching after looking for the bower.json file in the working directory?**  If the former, then I can just run `bower install` without worrying about navigating down the folder structure manually.

If `bower install` won't search for bower.json in the sub-directory, how could I include this command as part of an `npm start` script?  It seems the command would have to change directories into the "public" sub-directory and then run `bower install`.

Finally, this is mainly a deployment issue for me.  I'm using heroku which, when deploying, automatically runs `npm install` and the start scripts when it detects the presence of the package.json file.  So it seems that I need to include include `bower install` as part of the start scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: **yes**. `bower install` must run from the directory where your `bower.json` file exists.

You can most definitely create an `npm start` script which does this, however. It's easy! npm scripts are nothing more than shell commands that get executed verbatim.

So, let's say you've got a project that looks like this:

```
myapp
├── app.js
├── package.json
└── public
    └── bower.json
```

You can essentially create an `npm start` script that looks like this:

```
// ...
"start": "cd public && bower install && cd .. && node app.js"
// ...
```

This will ensure that when `npm start` is run, your bower dependencies get installed first, then your node app gets started.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for the very helpful answer.  This will work okay with heroku right?  Is this a common way to structure node projects?

Comment: Yeah! This is totally fine to do -- lots of places will do this. Also: if this is working for ya, you might want to mark this question as answered to help other people with the same question!

Comment: Okay, I think it is marked as answered now.  You just click on that check mark and it turns green right?  Thanks again.